# Elegir un elemento de un array de objetos en React

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, map

estoy realizando un proyecto de un clon de netflix en react
Tengo armado un .json para recurrir a el, tanto para las imagenes como para los titulos.

con un .map llamo a todos los .title que tengo en el array de objetos. Pero solo quiero elegir el title del segundo array... en uno de los componentes

que deberia utilizar para hacerlo? estoy un tanto flojo de js

```
{
    "series": [{
    "title": "BLACK SUMMER", 
    "image": "", 
    "description":"Una ansiada luna de miel. Un asesinato terrible. Varios sospechosos. Si sobreviven, serán unas vacaciones de ensueño.", 
    "seasons": {"1": [{"title": "Episode 1"}, {"title": "Episode 2"}]
  }}, {
    "title": "ARROW", 
    "image": "images/arrow.png", 
    "description":"Basada en las historietas de Flecha Verde, un próspero playboy se transforma en un superhéroe que salva a la ciudad de villanos, armado únicamente con un arco y flechas."},
    {
    "title": "The Seven Deadly Sins", 
    "image": "images/sevendeadlysins.png", 
    "description":""}]
}


function Main() {
  return (
    <div className="cover-wrapper">
      <div className="cover-content-wrapper">
        <h3 className="original-advise">Original de Netflix</h3>
        <h1 className="content-title">BLACK SUMMER</h1>
        <div className="series-infos">
          <p className="info">2012</p>
          <p className="info">16+</p>
          <p className="info">7 temporadas</p>
        </div>
        <div className="action-wrapper">
          <a href="#" className="action">
            Reproducir
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="action">
            + Mi lista
          </a>
        </div>
        <p className="content-season">Ve la temporada 1</p>
        <>
          <p className="content-description">Takawishi wirpi libi</p>
        </>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: Te refieres al array seasons?

Comment: No, yo quiero llamar al title: Arrow

Comment: lo que quieres hacer es mostrar todas las series de tu array verdad?

Comment: No, lo que quiero es solo llamar al title "Arrow"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)** si quieres que te devuelva un arreglo, o **[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find)** si quieres sólo el objeto

```js
const data = {
    "series": [{
    "title": "BLACK SUMMER", 
    "image": "", 
    "description":"Una ansiada luna de miel. Un asesinato terrible. Varios sospechosos. Si sobreviven, serán unas vacaciones de ensueño.", 
    "seasons": {"1": [{"title": "Episode 1"}, {"title": "Episode 2"}]
  }}, {
    "title": "ARROW", 
    "image": "images/arrow.png", 
    "description":"Basada en las historietas de Flecha Verde, un próspero playboy se transforma en un superhéroe que salva a la ciudad de villanos, armado únicamente con un arco y flechas."},
    {
    "title": "The Seven Deadly Sins", 
    "image": "images/sevendeadlysins.png", 
    "description":""}]
}

const filter = data.series.filter(item => item.title === 'ARROW')
console.log(`filter => ${JSON.stringify(filter)}`)

const find = data.series.find(item => item.title === 'ARROW')
console.log(`findBy => ${JSON.stringify(find)}`)
```

Ahora si quieres sólo el título del objeto que buscas, sería realizar un `map` al `filter`

```
const aux = data.series.filter(item => item.title === 'ARROW').map(item => item.title)
```

Nos comentas si te sirve!

Comment: Funciona, pero cuando re-renderizo yendo de una pagina a otra y volviendo a la inicial, no se renderiza. No se si me explico.

Comment: Te refieres a que vuelve a mostrar todo el listado?

Comment: No, a que no me lo vuelve a mostrar

Comment: Por eso, al cambiar de página y volver a la que tienes el listado, te vuelve a mostrar todo el listado, no sólo Arrow no?

Comment: una vez que vuelvo, no me muestra nada

Comment: En tu componente dónde estás renderizando esa lista? Porque sólo veo que estás creando datos en duro solamente. Manejas los estados de react? Hooks?

Comment: aparentemente, funcionó. Gracias!

Comment: Excelente! No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta ;)